# Fprintf in C is used but when I check the file is empty

Tags: c, printf

Trying to simply write to a .txt file in c for my network programming class but my file always ends up empty at the end of using this code. I've referenced plenty of sources and cannot find errors in this code. Maybe more sets of eyes can help. The `fprintf` is in the else statement at the very top.

```
// read the message from client and copy it in buffer
read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
// print buffer which contains the client contents
printf("From client: %s\t", buff);
if (loopcntr == 0)
{
    // filename = buff
    strcpy(filename, buff);
    // get time and add to filename
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
    strcat(filename, asctime (timeinfo));
    printf("Filename: %s\n", filename);
    // remove \n
    for (int i = 0; filename[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (filename[i] == '\n')
            filename[i] = ' ';
    }

    strcat(filename, ".txt");
    // create file with new filename
    fp = fopen(filename, "w+");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file...\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_CUR);
    // send filename back to client
    write(sockfd, filename, sizeof(filename));
    bzero(buff, MAX);
    n = 0;
}
else
{
    fprintf(fp, "%s\n", buff);
    strcpy(buff, "Message recieved...\n");
    write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
    bzero(buff, MAX);
    n = 0;
}
```

Comment: Provide a [mre].

Comment: Are you sure that the else statement is actually being called? Also, does `buff` actually contain content?

Comment: @Aplet123 Yes I know the else is being called and buff also contains a string

Comment: Does the program exit before you check whether the file is empty? Keep in mind that buffering is a thing; if you want content immediately flushed, you need to explicitly call `fflush()`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This was my issue! Thanks a ton! Solved!

Comment: Yes, you'd call it after the print. You do indeed need to pass it the file object to operate on.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I appreciate you, this solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

What `read(2)` returns is not `\0` terminated, so you cannot use it as a string for `%s` format descriptor directly.

If you reserve space in the buffer for a nul terminator, you can read the data (you can pass `write(2)` a *one subtracted* buffer size, and then take the number of bytes returned by `read()` and put in that offset a `\0` char.

```
int n = read(socket, buffer, sizeof buffer - 1);

/* check n < 0 for errors */
if (n < 0) {
   ERROR("read: errno = %d\n", errno);
   /* ... whatever more */
}

buffer[n] = '\0';  /* add a \0 at end of filled data */

printf("Buffer read: %s\n", buffer); /* now it is ok. */
```

or, if you don't want to have space to add your own `\0`,

```
printf("Buffer read: %.*s\n", n, buffer);
```

which allows you to pass a count of the number of chars in your buffer.  `printf` will not go further searching for characters, so it's not neccessary that the buffer is `\0` ended.

## note

All of this assumes that you are reading text data, not binary.   If so, the most probable thing is that you cannot `printf(3)` it at all, as `0x00` bytes will interrupt the printing, and control characters will trash your screen completely.